# Cannot get existing images/resources from server and how to get them

Tags: javascript, get

Sometimes ,may be when connection slow, browser cannot get image that already exist in server.
 I try to copy image src url that browser fail to get and open in new tab image can load properly just as you see in the picture. Chrome can load image and display it in console.
I wonder why this happen and how to solve this.

[image]

I try to reload images by add some parameter to prevent cache with this code

```
images[instance].onerror = function(){
        repeatPreload(this, 5);
}
function repeatPreload(Image, timeout){
    if(timeout > 0){
        setTimeout(function(){
            Image.src = Image.src.replace(/\?d=*[0-9]{6,}/g,"") + "?d=" + new Date().getTime();
            console.log("Fail to load image : " + Image.src + " , timeout : " + timeout);
            Image.onerror = repeatPreload(Image, timeout - 1);
        },2000);
    }else{
        Image["error"] = 1;
    }
}
```

I have already try to duplicate image folder and get image from duplicate folder when error happen but always fail.

Comment: Are you saying the browser is loading the images from its cache instead of from your webserver? What is the "error" you mention?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. I edited my question content.

Comment: Servers usually have a defined maximum number of connections per client. Depending on how your server if configured, it may drop the latest connections you initialize if previous connections are not closed yet. If this is it, you'll have to rearrange your preloading system to ensure the maximum parallel connections is never reached. What is the HTTP error you get when preloading fails?

Comment: Sorry for taking too long time. I have the screen capture of my problem here http://s12.postimage.org/vqubxw37f/PIC17_F2_tmp.jpg it has no response and status at all.

Comment: but in the next load , when I change image src , chrome got status 200 OK but my function that bind with image onerror still trigger.
Please help, thank you so much.